# Are there limits to number of attempts at entering a passphrase in bitcoin qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat, backup, passphrase

I have 2 wallet.dat backups from 2013

I am having trouble with accessing due to incorrect passphrase

Is there a limit to the number of attempts I can try to get the passphrase.

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange.com. This site works best when you ask one question at a time. Which question is most important to you right now?

Comment: I have edited your question to focus on what I believe is the part that is mainly holding you back currently. You can use the "Edited" link to undo my changes if you feel they are unhelpful. Interested readers can use the question history to see the original question in full.

Answer (score 0):

I am confident there is no limit to the number of attempts at entering the passphrase.

---

This is because the authors know that any such limit can be bypassed by, for example, installing on a VM and restoring an initial snapshot when the limit is reached. You could also divide the work between multiple parallel VMs. Therefore I expect authors are more likely to introduce rate limiting rather than waste effort implementing an upper bound to the number of attempts.

There are tools like BTCrecover and PyWallet which may help but which are not especially user friendly for novices.

Offering money to strangers is a certain way of being overwhelmed by offers from confidence tricksters and thieves.